# Sort data in query by a column

Tags: mysql

I have a query meant to get all users not being followed by the user.

I want to sort them to match his selected modes - modes is a json string from 0 to 3 (for example, [0] / [0,2] / [1,3]...) and I want to show the user the best results first.

For example if the users' modes are [1,3] it will show users with [x,1] / [1] / [1,x,x]... first and then the rest. If he has [1,2] first it will show the same and then [2,x] etc... and then the rest.

Notice that modes could be empty as well if the user haven't defined any modes. (Empty string is undefined, and not []).

I tried to order by users.modes but it sorts it regardless what's the user's modes are.

```
SELECT *, users.uid, users.id 
FROM  users 
LEFT JOIN follows 
ON (follows.fid = users.uid AND follows.uid = 3443963) 
WHERE follows.id IS NULL AND users.uid != 3443963 
ORDER BY users.modes DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?

Comment: What do you want to know in specifics? Users has id, uid and modes columns. follows has uid (user following) and fid (user being followed)

Comment: Sample data, so we can run the query and see how it performs vs. how it should perform. Also are you using 5.7.8 and a JSON data type, or is your `modes` just varchar?

Comment: It's just text. This is how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/nmvu3a